# Start an action on returning from settings screen android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

### My Scenario:

1. I am opening an activity
2. I am doing a validation(checking internet)
3. On false of that validation, launching an alert dialog
4. Now I go to settings enable internet comeback by pressing back
   button
5. The dialog is not dismissed it still is in the screen
6. My objective is to restart the activity when i return from settings
   screen

---

### CODE

```
public void open(){
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.searchFilterLocationMessage));
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Ok, 
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS) ;
                this.startActivity(intent);
                 */
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);


            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 0) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    }//onActivityResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch the setting intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

and fetch the current *Activity* in `onResume()` method:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // Do your work
}
```

After getting back from the setting screen, your `onResume()` method will be call and here you can fetch your location.

Answer (score 12):

Launching an `Activity` whith the *`singleTask`* launch mode by calling *`startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)`* returns a cancel result immediately. You can see it in debugger that *`onActivityResult()`* is called even before the system settings `Activity` starts.

As a quick workaround I suggest using a flag indicating whether the settings `Activity` was called or not. Like

1. setting a flag

   ```
   private boolean flag = false;
   ```
2. using *`startActivity()`* istead of *`startActivityForResult()`*

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
       startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
       flag = true;
   }
   ```
3. checking the flag in *`onResume()`*

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
       if (flag) {
           startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
           finish();
       }
   }
   ```